# What is the type of struct.self in swift?

Tags: swift, self, jsondecoder

I have a structural variable that extends Codable protocol, and want to memorize its type, so that I can use it next time in JSONDecoder. However, when a private variable is declared, its class needs to be specified, but whatever class I'm trying use, I cannot use the result later in JSONDecoder. So my question is what is the type of myVariable.self?

I have this problem, because I want to specify the class when a view decoder is initialized. During the initialization, I call the following function (this part of the code works well):

```
 func getData<T: Codable>(fromURL: String, onSuccess: @escaping (T) -> Void, onError: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: fromURL)!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                        onError(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                        onError("Invalid data or response")
                        return
                    }
                do {
                    if response.statusCode == 200 {
                        let ret = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        onSuccess(ret)
                    } else {
                        let err = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIError.self, from: data)
                        onError(err.message)
                    }
                } catch {
                    onError(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

This part of the code works well. However, if I need to upload more data, I need to know T.self for proper decoder, so I need to keep it. A solution could be to create a private variable:

```
private var type: ??? // what type should I put here?
```

and to write in the function's body

```
type = T.self
```

But whichever type I try, it doesn't work.

What type should I put there? Or, maybe, there are some other solutions?

Comment: Inside the method it's `T.Type`

Comment: Yep, thanks, Vadan, inside the method it is. But how to declare it properly outside the method, so it would be available afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the property

```
private var type: Codable.Type
```

or wrap the method in a generic struct or class and declare the property

```
class CodableWrapper<T : Codable> {

    private var type: T.Type
    ...
```

Comment: When I replace ```JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)``` with ```SONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)```  or ```type.self```, it says: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Codable.Type?, from: Data)'